# Mocha Unit Testing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I want to write unit testing for Restful Endpoint, but whenever I run npm test. I get the error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined .

```
let chai = require('chai')
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
let home = require('../routes/home')
let user = require('../routes/users')
//Assertion Style
chai.should()

chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('chow Api', () => {
  //  users
    describe("GET /api/chow/home", () => {
        it('it should render Welcome to Homepage', (done) =>{
            chai.request(home)
            .get("/api/chow/home")
            .end((err, response) =>{
                response.should.have.status(200)
                response.body.should.be('string')
                done()
            })
        })
    })

    describe('GET /api/chow/users', () => {
        it('it should GET all the users', (done) => {
            chai.request(user)
            .get("/api/chow/users")
            .end((err, response) =>{
                response.should.have.status(200)
                response.should.be.a('array')
                done()
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: can you please provide the abbreviated content of your home and user routes. More specifically what you export from those modules. And also provide the full stack of the error.

Comment: @jeeves, though I can not get exact code of the  OP, but I think I have reproduced the exact error. Here's the repo, check it out https://github.com/IamLizu/express-test-dummy

Comment: does your endpoint even start without testing ?

Comment: @user3732793, check my repo, that does.

Answer (score 1):

Follow changes to be done for the Mocha test to be working

in `index.js`,
you should add this line `module.exports = app;` for the server to start.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const homeController = require("./routes/home");

app.use("/home", homeController);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server started at port", port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

in `test/routes/home.js`, you should add `.get("/home")` and `res.text.should.equal("Hello World!");`
to pass Mocha test for `/home` endpoint

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHTTP = require("chai-http");

const mainEntryPoint = require("../../index");

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHTTP);

describe("Entry point", () => {
    context("GET /", () => {
        it("should get greeting back", (done) => {
            chai.request(mainEntryPoint)
                .get("/home")
                .end((err, res) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.text.should.equal("Hello World!");
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I exported the app and made the change in the test file, still same. Here's a snap, https://imgur.com/a/nT8QnK1

Comment: `const mainEntryPoint = require("../../index");` you have to change the entry as well. Try copy pasting the entire code @Hasan

Comment: @Hasan https://github.com/IamLizu/express-test-dummy/pull/1 please check this pull request

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't change source of `mainEntryPoint`. Yes, it works. Can you explain what was happening and why it happened? Is it not possible to test a separate route module? Do we have to test the main app like this always?

Comment: in `chai.request` main file `index.js` has to be the entry point because the server has to start and the code to start the server is in index.js and after that, you have to mention the endpoint that you want to test in this case `/home` and according to thtat can check for the expectted response @Hasan

Comment: I see. Thanks, I have actually read an article or two, but surely missed that part. Can you please link any good resource on using `mocha` and `chai`?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/test-a-node-restful-api-with-mocha-and-chai
https://medium.com/@osahonoboite/testing-restful-apis-using-mocha-chai-and-chai-http-plugin-4b9feb45d50
you can check these blogs... digital ocean blog will give you detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
const app = require("./app.js")
chai.request(app).get("/api/chow/users")
chai.request(app).get("/api/chow/users")
```

Or

```
chai.request(home).get("/")
chai.request(user).get("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```js
....
.get("/") // This should be a relative path from current route
.end((err, response) =>{
    if(err) return done(err)
    response.should.have.status(200)
    response.body.should.be('string')
    done()
});
```

I cannot say for 100% sure without seeing the codes for routes. But, `TypeError: cannot do whatever with undefined` occurs when you access an object property or method which is undefined. I would suggest printing the responses to get some insight. Also, please share your route logic. Without that, it's hard to determine the source of the error

Comment: I have tested on my test repo, unfortunately, no avail. Here's a reproducible repo https://github.com/IamLizu/express-test-dummy